# CDI deployment failure:WELD-000163: Non-unique bean deployment identifier detected on migration from payara4.1 to payara 4.1.1.164

Tags: glassfish, cdi, weld, payara

Updated my glassfish payara from 4.1 to 4.1.1.164(with WELD 2.4.0 Final). But the below exception is reported, though the link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2165 says it is fixed.

Any issues with payara server ? Thanks for the help

```
BeanDeployment [beanDeploymentArchiveId=test.ejb],    
BeanDeployment [beanDeploymentArchiveId=test2.ejb] 
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.DeploymentVisitor.visit(DeploymentVisitor.java:51) 
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer(WeldStartup.java:241) 
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:69) 
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:220) 
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131) 
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:329) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:164) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:597) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:484) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:412) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233) 
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) 
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: In the stacktrace you posted, there are only two archives and they have different IDs. Are there any other archives? Have you followed the suggestions in [WELD-2165](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2165) issue? I suppose your problem is also linked to some portable extension?

Comment: Yes https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2165 is fixed for wildfly but not for payara. Got response from google groups as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/payara-forum/JSmOQ5VcD0E/UtrrZKhHDAAJ

Comment: Note that this is not a problem of Weld but an integration issue (WildFly, Payara, etc.). WELD-2165 is a feature request to detect ambiguous BeanDeploymentArchive identifiers.